# PHP Eclipse installation is giving an error

Tags: php, eclipse

I am trying to program PHP in Eclipse, but the installation is not working correctly. I follow the instructions on this website:
https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

I paste the link named there in help -> Install new software, but it gives the following error:

[image: error code]

Comment: You may be able to use the default `All available sites`, and search for `PDT`. That's all I had to do, I believe. (but I've had PDT installed for awhile now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Help > Install New Software...* dialog work with [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest).